# Oracle SQL: Need syntax to reduce result in query

Tags: sql

Can someone help me get correct syntax for the results I need? In the query below, the subquery gets two courses (A and B).  The entire query gets the period they are held.  However, I only want the period that both classes have in common.

```
select m.period
  from course
  join meets m
 using (start_yy, school, class_cd)
  join section s
 using (start_yy, school, class_cd, section)
 where start_yy = '11'
   and school = 'MYSCH'
   and class_cd in (select cl.class_cd
                      from crslink cl, linkhead lh
                     where cl.start_yy = '11'
                       and cl.school = 'MYSCH'
                       and cl.seq_number = lh.seq_number)   
 order by period;
```

The two classes in the subquery are held multiple periods but period 4 is the only period they both have in common.  How do I get that result?

Results are: 1,2,4,7

I need: 4

Here are the table structures containing the fields used in query.

```
TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_ID,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,DATA_LENGTH
COURSE    ,1        ,START_YY   ,VARCHAR2 ,2
COURSE    ,2        ,SCHOOL     ,VARCHAR2 ,4
COURSE    ,3        ,CLASS_CD   ,VARCHAR2 ,10
CRSLINK   ,1        ,START_YY   ,VARCHAR2 ,2
CRSLINK   ,2        ,SCHOOL     ,VARCHAR2 ,4
CRSLINK   ,3        ,CLASS_CD   ,VARCHAR2 ,10
CRSLINK   ,4        ,SEQ_NUMBER ,NUMBER   ,22
LINKHEAD  ,1        ,START_YY   ,VARCHAR2 ,2
LINKHEAD  ,2        ,SCHOOL     ,VARCHAR2 ,4
LINKHEAD  ,7        ,SEQ_NUMBER ,NUMBER   ,22
MEETS     ,1        ,START_YY   ,VARCHAR2 ,2
MEETS     ,2        ,SCHOOL     ,VARCHAR2 ,4
MEETS     ,3        ,CLASS_CD   ,VARCHAR2 ,10
MEETS     ,4        ,SECTION    ,VARCHAR2 ,3
MEETS     ,6        ,PERIOD     ,VARCHAR2 ,2
SECTION   ,1        ,START_YY   ,VARCHAR2 ,2
SECTION   ,2        ,SCHOOL     ,VARCHAR2 ,4
SECTION   ,3        ,CLASS_CD   ,VARCHAR2 ,10
SECTION   ,4        ,SECTION    ,VARCHAR2 ,3
```

Comment: you'll need to explaing the column values in more detail because I can't figure out what they mean...

Comment: Could you post your tables structure?

Comment: start_yy , school and class_cd fields belongs to which table in outer query

Comment: write down the table structure in post.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct m.period
  from course
  join meets m
 using (start_yy, school, class_cd)
  join section s
 using (start_yy, school, class_cd, section)
 where start_yy = '11'
   and school = 'MYSCH'
   and class_cd exists (select 1 
                      from crslink cl, linkhead lh
                     where cl.class_cd =course.class_cd 
                         And cl.start_yy = '11'
                       and cl.school = 'MYSCH'
                       and cl.seq_number = lh.seq_number)   
 order by period;
```

**IInd Solution:**

prefix the table name with the three fields in where clause in following query.

```
select m.period
  from course
  join meets m
 using (start_yy, school, class_cd)
  join section s
 using (start_yy, school, class_cd, section)
 join 
 crslink cl on cl.class_cd = class_cd
 join 
 linkhead lh on cl.seq_number = lh.seq_number
 where start_yy = '11'
   and school = 'MYSCH'
   and class_cd 
   and cl.start_yy = '11'
   and cl.school = 'MYSCH'
   and cl.class_cd is not null
   and lh.seq_number is not null
 order by period;
```

Comment: I can create the sql using left join if you prefix the table name with fields with all fields in the query you posted. That will be more readable.

Comment: Sorry, the results didn't display formatted.  It is row number, class, section and period

Comment: start_yy , school and class_cd fields in where clause in outer query belongs to which table.

Comment: The inner query is retrieving classes that need to be scheduled as a link by period.  The outer query is the classes, sections, and meeting times (i.e period).  A class may be available in multiple periods however the "link" says these two classes need to be scheduled in the same period.  Period 4 is the only comon period between the two.  I need 4 to be the only result.

Comment: I posted an edit of my original query with prefixes.  The three fields you question make up the key to course and meets.  Does that answer your question Romil?

Comment: I did not find a "one query" way of getting my results.  However, using my query and a temporary table in the program I am able to retrieve what I need.  Thanks to all for considering answering my question.